# Javascript counter for tracking calls of Open Weather Map API

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

I use the free API of Open Weather Map. I can use 1000 API calls per day by using One Call API. I now want to track these calls. Open Weather Map doesn't provide these statistics. So how can I build a simple Javascript counter for tracking calls of Open Weather Map API? I only need the number of calls per day. No further information. How do I start? I use this on a website made with html and javascript  for people with intellectual disabilities using text-to-speech.

Comment: Please be more specific, what kind of application. What do you have now? What have you tried?

Comment: I added "I use this on a website made with html and javascript for people with intellectual disabilities using text-to-speech." I don't know where to begin to track these calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your API call with js, you just have to call your own API to update your DB or an internal file who keep the count.

If you make your API call with your backend (php, nodejs, ...), just update an internal file who will keep the count